# SQL Divide one count result by another OR Alternate solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, divide

I have a table with the following schema.

Relational Database Schema:

```
 Hotel = hotelNo, hotelName, city
 Room = roomNo, hotelNo(FK), type, rate
 Guest = guestNo, guestName, guestAddress
 Booking = hotelNo(FK), guestNo(FK), dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo(FK)
```

There are entries in each table however their data isn't completely relevant to this question.

I need to calculate the average number of booking made for each hotel, ensuring that I include the hotels which do not currently have bookings.

I have this :

-- Call this select 1

```
select count(*)
from booking b, hotel h
where b.hotelNo=h.hotelNo;
```

-- Call this select 2

```
select count(*) 
from hotel;
```

Select 1 returns the total number of bookings. Select 2 returns the total number of hotels. If I could simply divide the output of count in select 1 by the output of count in select 2 I would have my answer.

If this is possible can someone please help me with the code, otherwise can someone think of an alternate solution to achieve the same result?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If by "average number of bookings", you just want to divide the two numbers, then you can do:

```
select count(b.HotelNo) / count(distinct h.hotelNo)
from hotel h left join
     booking b
     on h.hotelNo = b.hotelNo;
```

Comment: By doing the math manually the result is 2.5 Using this method the result is 2.8? Any ideas?

Comment: @Dylan . . . Yes.  The `left join` was bringing in a "blank" booking record for each hotel.  I just fixed the code to only count the matches.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view say temp to get count of rooms per hotel[ The data you 'see' in a view, is not actually stored anywhere, and is generated from the tables on the fly.]

```
create view temp 
as select hotelNo,count(*) as cnt from room group by hotelNo;
```

Use following query to fetch avg.

```
select booking.hotelNo,count(*) / cnt
from booking ,temp
where booking.hotelNo = temp.hotelNo
group by booking.hotelNo;
```

or

```
select booking.hotelNo,count(*) / cnt
from booking 
INNER JOIN temp
on booking.hotelNo = temp.hotelNo
group by booking.hotelNo;
```

This will not include hotels that do not have any booking.